# Printing out highest value item from nested list

Tags: python, printing, calculator, nested-lists, python-3.9

The code needs to print out the breed of dog that has earned the shop the most money. I know i need to multiply together the quantity (item[2]) and money (item[3]) to find how much money each dog has earned the shop first but I don't know how to get the system to print out the best selling dog. It has to be solved within the def function, does anyone know what I could do to solve this, Thanks!

```
# List of transactions [[breed, Dogname, quantity bought, price, age of dog]]
lst_dogs = [
    ["Pitbull", "Rover", 2, 90, 5],
    ["Greyhound", "Jess", 1, 100, 6],
    ["Lab", "Rose", 1,85, 3],
    ["Pitbull", "Daisy", 1, 90, 3],
]

def best_dog():
    sum = 0

    for i in range(len(lst_dogs)):

        item = lst_dogs[i]

        for item in lst_dogs:
            amount = item[2]
            price = item[3]
            total = amount * price
            sum += total

print("The dog which has earned the most money for the shop is", item[0])
```

Desired Output: The dog which has earned the most money for the shop is: Pitbull

Actual Output: Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 3):

Use the `max` function with a key:

```py
lst_dogs = [
    ["Pitbull", "Rover", 2, 90, 5],
    ["Greyhound", "Jess", 1, 100, 6],
    ["Lab", "Rose", 1,85, 3],
    ["Pitbull", "Daisy", 1, 90, 3],
]

best_dog = max(lst_dogs, key=lambda item: item[2] * item[3])

print("The dog which has earned the most money for the shop is", best_dog[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Take this @cgl345

```
def givebest(lst_dogs):
    best_dog = max(lst_dogs, key=lambda item: item[2] * item[3])
    print(f'Best dog is {best_dog[0]}')
```

Comment: def givebest(lst_dogs):
    best_dog = max(lst_dogs, key=lambda item: item[2] * item[3])
    print(f'Best dog is {best_dog[0]}')

Comment: def givebest(lst_dogs):
    best_dog = max(lst_dogs, key=lambda item: item[2] * item[3]);
    print(f'Best dog is {best_dog[0]}')